# How do I re-install 11.10 and wipe out 12.04? 

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, iso, downgrade, dell-mini-10

I have had nothing but problems with 12.04 and want to return to 11.04.

I do not want to try to fix it at this time and want to go back to what worked well for me.

Can someone point me to the appropriate ISO download for 11,10 and instructions I need  to re-install it on my Dell Inspiron Mini.

I will be using a Microsoft Windows 7 to download 11.10 onto a thumb drive.

Am I right to assume by doing this I will have no issues?

Answer (score 1):

1. Here's the 11.10 i386 ISO you need for your Mini:

   - http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
2. Use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sf.net) to "burn" the ISO to a USB.

   [image]

   - UNetbootin looks like the above screenshot **BUT** you select the DiskImage option at the bottom and use the `...` button on the right to select the ISO you downloaded in Step 1.
3. Boot from the USB, and select the "use entire disk" option in the Ubuntu Installer to wipe out 12.04 and install 11.10 over it -- that shouldn't give you any problems since 12.04 will be completely erased.

Comment: Can you tell me more about #2 "Use Unetbootin to "burn" the ISO to a USB?

How do I pull up that blue bordered box?

Do I need to download the ISO through Unetbootin?  I have already downloaded the ISO alone onto my USB.

I am using a Microsoft XP machine to create this disk if that makes a difference.

Comment: Okay, here are better questions (I think): 1- Can I get my USB set up using my Dell Mini with Ubuntu 12.04?  Where do I need to save the iso to?  I used the Software center to get Unetbootin but I am not seeing where to find the ISO it just gives me "computer" or something else but lists nothing under those.  2) In the past I put the Iso on my ext hd and then created the start up disk on the USB using my Windows 7 computer.   The directions above do not look like the same process and so I am confused what to do and how.   Can someone spell it out a little more for me.  Thanks